# My javascript is returning this error: $.ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typeerror

**Not sure what's wrong but I'm getting this error from my chrome console:**

```
jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:1244 jQuery.Deferred exception: $.ajax is not a function TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/UseTime/js/example.js:3:7)
    at j (file:///C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/UseTime/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:1193:55)
    at k (file:///C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/UseTime/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:1199:45) undefined
r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:1244
jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:1247 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (example.js:3)
    at j (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:1193)
    at k (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:1199)
```

From this JavaScript:

```
$(function() { //when the DOM is ready
    var times; //declare global variable
    $.ajax({ //set up request
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { //before requesting data
            if (xhr.overrideMimeType) { //if supported
                xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json"); // set MIME to prevent errors
            }
        }
    });
    //funciton that collect data from the json file
    function loadTimetable() { //decalre function
        $.getJSON('data/example.json') //try to collect json data
            .done(function (data) { //if succesful
                times = data; //store in variable
            }).fail(function () { //if a problem: show message
                $('#event').html('Sorry! we couldnt load your time table at the moment');
            });
    }
    loadTimetable(); //call the function

    //CLICK ON TEH EVENT TO LOAD A TIME TABLE
    $('#content').on('click', '#event a', function (e) { //user clicks on place
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent loading page
        var loc = this.id.toUpperCase(); //get value of id attr
        var newContent = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < times[loc].length; i++) { // loop through sessions
            newContent += '<li><span class = "time">' + times[loc][i].time + '</span>';
            newContent += '<a href = "descriptions.html#';
            newContent += times[loc][i].title.replace(/ /g, '-') + '">';
            newContent += times[loc][i].title + '</a></li>';
        }
        $('#sessions').html('<ul>' + newContent + '</ul>'); // Display Time
        $('#event a.current').removeClass('current'); // update selected link
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $('#details').text('');
    });

    //CLICK ON A SESSION TO LEAD THE DESCRIPTION
    $('#content').on('click', '#sessions li a', function (e) { //click on session
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent loading
        var fragment = this.href; //title is in href
        fragment = fragment.replace('#', ' #'); //Add Space before #
        $('#details').load(fragment); //to load info
        $('#sessions a.current').removeClass('current'); //update selected
    });

    //CLICK ON PRIMARY NAVIGATION
    $('nav a').on('click', function (e) { //click on nav
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent loading
        var url = this.href; //get UR: to load
        $('nav a.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $('#container').remove(); //remove old
        $('#content').load(url + ' #container').hide().fadeIn('slow'); // add new
    });
});
```

I'm not sure if it's an issue with the way I'm initiating .ajax or if my jquery isn't correctly implemented. I think it is. Any Thoughts?

edit: here's the html that goes with the script above

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>UseTime</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="jq-load.html">HOME</a>
            <a href="jq-load.html2">PROFILE</a>
            <a href="jq-load.html4">MANAGE TASKS</a>
            <a href="usetime.html">TIME TABLE</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="content">
        <div id="container">
            <div class="third">
                <div id="event">
                    <a id="class1" href="class1.html"><img src="" alt="class1" /> Class 1 </a>
                    <a id="class2" href="class2.html"><img src="" alt="class2" /> Class 2 </a>
                    <a id="class3" href="class3.html"><img src="" alt="class3" /> Class 3 </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="third">
                <div id="sessions"> Select a Class from the left </div>
            </div>
            <div class="third">
                <div id="details"> Details </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- container -->
    </section>
    <!-- content -->

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/example.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you link any jQuery to Your Code???  Link the Jquery​ before any other javascript. it may work.

Comment: yea yea it's in the html that calls this, I'll throw it up into the post

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You are using slim version of jQuery. It Doesn't support ajax Calling.
Use

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

instead of it.

> **Slim build**
>
> Sometimes you don’t need ajax, or you prefer to use one of the many
>   standalone libraries that focus on ajax requests. And often it is
>   simpler to use a combination of CSS and class manipulation for all
>   your web animations. Along with the regular version of jQuery that
>   includes the ajax and effects modules, we’ve released a “slim” version
>   that excludes these modules. All in all, it excludes ajax, effects,
>   and currently deprecated code. The size of jQuery is very rarely a
>   load performance concern these days, but the slim build is about 6k
>   gzipped bytes smaller than the regular version – 23.6k vs 30k. These
>   files are also available in the npm package and on the CDN:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.js
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js
```

Referred from [jQuery Blog](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/09/22/jquery-3-1-1-released/)

Comment: ohhhh I didnt know that, that makes sense, I'll give that a try. Thanks

Comment: You many refer it from here. https://blog.jquery.com/2016/09/22/jquery-3-1-1-released/

Comment: This answer is pure gold.. Took me 2 hours. Why are they removing AJAX - Its one of the best functions around jQuery.

Comment: @gies0r Ajax is removed only from slim version only, If you need to build a simple app which doesn't need any ajax calling, or you have a standalone ajax library you can use this slim version.

Comment: @AdhershMNair: Sure - Just belive that most applications need this feature

Comment: Bootstrap sample template under 'Getting Started' loads the slim version. Had to snag proper from their CDN at https://code.jquery.com/.

Answer (score 13):

jQuery 3 slim version doesn't support ajax.

According to the [release docs](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/),

> Along with the regular version of jQuery that includes the ajax and
>   effects modules, we’re releasing a “slim” version that excludes these
>   modules. All in all, it **excludes ajax**, effects, and currently
>   deprecated code.

To use `.ajax` method, simply use the full version one.

Try this one (jquery-3.2.1.min.js) instead of slim (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js)

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```