# How to make a subscribe button using php, ajax and jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am completely new to Ajax and jQuery in practical terms, but I'm trying to make a subscribe button for my site using both.

Now I have read most of the documentation to Ajax and jQuery and have come up with a little code to do just that.

The problem is that it isn't working and I can't for the life of me see why.

I click the subscribe button and nothing happens:
The subscribe.php script doesn't run and the database isn't updated and no alert is showing - like I said... nothing happens

Hope someone can help.

Code so far
jQuery.js (loaded in the index.php that holds all other pages at the start of the body-tag)

```
<body>
// Load official jQuery-library
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
// Load my own jQuery-script file
<script src="jQuery/jQuery.js"></script>
.
.
.
// Load all pages (videos.php, channel.php,...) as needed
</body>

// Code in my own jQuery.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";
    $("#subscribe").click(function(subscribeData){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'../scripts/subscribe.php',
            data:{randomStringUser:subscribeData},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data){
                alert("You subscribed");// Do what you do after subscribe.php has done it's thing
                // just to test I just put an alert here
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("Didn't work");// Do what you do if mission failed
                // just to test I just put an alert here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP on top of the page where the subscribe button is located (ie. channel.php) and subscribe-button code

```
<?php

    .
    .
    .
    $randomStringUser = $_GET['channel'];
    $subscribeData = json_encode($randomStringUser);

?>
// Page html
.
.
.

// Subscribe-button
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="subscribe">
    Subscribe
</button>
```

subscribe.php from the ajax-call

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $randomStringUser = $_POST['randomStringUser'];

    // $_SESSION['id'] is set with users-id when user log in
    // So if user logged in use that id as $subscriberID
    if ( isset ( $_SESSION['id'] ) ) {
        $subscriberID = $_SESSION['id'];
    }

    "SELECT id FROM userinfo WHERE randomString = ? LIMIT 1" // using $randomStringUser as ?

    // Use the id found in SELECT as $subscriptionID

    "INSERT INTO usersubscription ( subscriberID , subscriptionID ) VALUES ( ? , ? )" // Using $subscriberID and $subscriptionID from above as ?
```

Comment: Are you able to check the Network tab in the Google Chrome developer tools to see if a request to `../scripts/subscribe.php` is being made? (`F12` -> Network)

Comment: just did and no request is being made... very strange hmmm...

Comment: ok I had to check errors in network... so no request is sent but it throws a "uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function"

Comment: I found your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212202 --- You are using a slim version of jQuery which does not include `$.ajax`

Comment: Replace your jQuery link with `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @Acidic - god d*#¤* - m*#¤¤ f*#¤¤%.... it's always something soooo simple.... thank you so very much... switched to the min-versoin and it works like a charm... can't believe I spent the better part of a day troubleshooting the code for it just to be this... hehe... please write your comment as an answer so I can give you your checkmark and an upvote - you the man :)

Comment: hahahah it's always some stupid little thing like that which sucks so much time from you. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajax` is not found because you are referencing a *slim* version of jQuery rather than the whole library.

I suggest you use the full minified version of jQuery so you can use it to it's full potential.

Try replacing your `<script>` tag with the following:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```