# AJAX Success call a defined function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm having trouble calling an external function on success. The ideal solution would let me also pass in some parameters to the function!

i.e. `success: writeToConsole("successful");`

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".portalControls").find(".syncButton").click(triggerSync);    
});

function triggerSync(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sync",
    dataType: "text",
    success: writeToConsole,
      error: writeToConsole
    }
  });
}

function writeToConsole(consoleText) {
  $.find("portalConsole").text(consoleText);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Errors I get: `"Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function"`.
I never get the request on my server.

EDIT: Problem was to do with having a jQuery slim script on another page. Removing that fixed the error.

Comment: You don't have problems with defining a success function. Your problem is *"Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function"*.

Comment: Make sure Jquery is loaded before this script

Comment: @KumarShubham How?

Comment: @Tomalak Should I change the title?

Comment: Also make sure that your version of Jquery supports ajax. I mean as the answer below says

Comment: The script tag for Jquery should be above than the script tag of your personal js file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My javascript is returning this error: $.ajax is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212202/my-javascript-is-returning-this-error-ajax-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @KumarShubham `$(document).ready()` should throw an error long before the Ajax method. It's not the script's placement, it's just the wrong library.

Comment: @JJJ yep, I think I missed that

Comment: @Josh Googling your error (use double quotes for exact matches) brings up a **generous** amount of hits that explain exactly what's wrong. Always search first, please.

Comment: @Tomalak I did search! In fact I even found the slim version of jQuery answer, I just didn't realise I had it! I downloaded it directly from the jQuery website and there wasn't any obvious reference to it being the slim version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using slim version of jQuery. It Doesn't support ajax Calling. Use following

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

**Update**
Check out following 
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1d5jt08/)

Comment: As a kind of additional explanation on his answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery
this link is explaning on the difference between jquery-slim version and normal version

Comment: I switched to this, it still doesn't work. Same error.

Comment: @Josh:Check oout jsfiddle

Comment: @santoshsingh I checked it out, thanks for that. It still doesn't work for me for some reason, with the exact same error. It shows the right script on the dev tools, not sure why it's not working.

Comment: try this <script src=//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: I figured out the problem! I had a jQuery slim script loaded on another page, and I think that must have been cached in some way, overwriting the non-slim version?

Answer (score -1):

As @Santosh said make sure you add the following code in your head:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Also I found out there is a few errors in your code, I tried to find out what you want to achieve and make a code out from it, you should look though is this what you want

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".portalControls").find(".syncButton").click(triggerSync);

});

function triggerSync(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sync",
    dataType: "text",
    success: writeToConsole("fine"),
    error: writeToConsole("error")
  });
}

function writeToConsole(consoleText) {
  $(".portalConsole").text(consoleText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="portalControls">
  <button class="syncButton">
click
</button>
</div>
<div class="portalConsole">

</div>
```

For the issue I found out first there is one more `}` here

```
    success: writeToConsole,
    error: writeToConsole
}
^
});
```

Second, I don't know why you use `$.find("portalConsole").text(consoleText);`, if you want to change the text, I'll use `$(".portalConsole").text("text here...")` also notice there isn't a `.` or a `#` before portalConsol.

Answer (score -2):

Just add the above CDN script tag

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`