# Put method with Ajax (the script isn't triggered)

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I am implementing Put method with Ajax:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submitPut').click(  function () {
                console.log("click");
                var sendName = $('#name').val();
                var sendDescription = $('#description').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/musicalstyle',    //Your api url
                    type: 'PUT',   //type is any HTTP method
                    data: {
                        name: sendName,
                        description: sendDescription,

                    },      //Data as js object
                    success: function () {
                    }
                })
                ;

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form> 
        <label for="name">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" id="name"  />
        <label for="description">Descripción</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="description"/>
        <input id="submitPut" type="button"  value="SubmitPut">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This form is working fine but when introduce it on real environment the script isn't called (my view in production environment is using Thymeleaf and Boostrap). It's like `<button class="btn btn-primary" id="submitPut" type="button">Actualizar</button>` isn't triggering the submitPut function.

Here form of production environment:

```
    <form>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Descripción</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description">
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
         <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submitPut" type="button">Actualizar</button>
    </form>
```

How can I force to button call ajax function?

Thanks,

Comment: your code is working fine , does your browser console has any error? Also does this form is dynamically generated?

Comment: @Swati this form isn't generated dinamically but other forms in the same page are generated. In additional, browser console is showing the next error: ```Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (musicalstyle:42)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (VM26 jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (VM26 jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)```

Comment: Could you show how you import JQuery library and the whole script in which you call the ajax function??

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212249) answer this  will solve your problem.

Comment: @Eric I am importing with ```<script src="../js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/jquery.slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script><script src="../js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script></body>
``` And I am only call the ajax function in form below

Comment: That is because you use slim version of jquery. Use the standard file.

Comment: @Swati seems that as you show, I should import the JQuery with ```<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>```

Comment: @onox check and see it should work.

Comment: Are we CERTAIN there is ONLY ONE button on the webpage with the id = "submitPut"?

Comment: There was only a button which id is submitPut. The ajax script didn't called because JQuery wasn't imported correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your **id** of **input** is `submit` while you called onclick function on query, `submitPut`.
So,

```
<input id="submitPut" type="button"  value="SubmitDelete"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Biplove I have eddited my comment. Id of input is equal than name of onclick function.

Answer (score 0):

After import JQuery with 
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` 
`<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/jquery.slim.min.js">`  `<\/script>')</script><script src="../js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script></body>`

Ajax is executed.

My method Put in Controller should redirect to another view and seems to be redirecting. The Spring logs show:

```
2020-05-21 16:04:15.367 DEBUG 552 --- [nio-8182-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : PUT "/musicalstyle", parameters={masked}
2020-05-21 16:04:15.368 DEBUG 552 --- [nio-8182-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.musicnet.springboot.controller.SystemAdministratorController#updateStyle(Style, Model)
2020-05-21 16:04:15.558 DEBUG 552 --- [nio-8182-exec-9] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected '*/*' given [*/*]
2020-05-21 16:04:15.632 DEBUG 552 --- [nio-8182-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

Here the style is updated so put method is working fine but the view isn't showed on browser. I suspect that Spring doesn't have any problem in order to redirect view, the problem is that ajax script isn't redirecting to the returned view.

How can I modify the ajax script to process the view returned by Spring?

**Edit**

In fact, I get the redirect putting in ajax script:

```
success: function () {
            window.location.reload();
     }
```