# Custom post type Ajax Load More not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to make an Ajax Load More function for my posts inside WordPress. The only thing is that I am getting an error:

> custom.js?ver=5.5.1:11 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
> at HTMLAnchorElement. (custom.js?ver=5.5.1:11)
> at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (VM1605 jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
> at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (VM1605 jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)

Code:

```
jQuery(function($){ // use jQuery code inside this to avoid "$ is not defined" error
    $('.misha_loadmore').click(function(){

        var button = $(this),
            data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts, // that's how we get params from wp_localize_script() function
            'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
        };

        $.ajax({ // you can also use $.post here
            url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.text('Loading...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
            },
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) {
                    button.text( 'More posts' ).prev().before(data); // insert new posts
                    misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;

                    if ( misha_loadmore_params.current_page == misha_loadmore_params.max_page )
                        button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button

                    // you can also fire the "post-load" event here if you use a plugin that requires it
                    // $( document.body ).trigger( 'post-load' );
                } else {
                    button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212249/10606400) answer .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My javascript is returning this error: $.ajax is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212202/my-javascript-is-returning-this-error-ajax-is-not-a-function)