# AJAX does not request to url page to get success response

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem where the AJAX does not request to delete_data.php to get success response. Why is this occur? AJAX does not even go to delete_data.php to execute the code. When I click the Delete Data button, it will pop up confirmation to delete, but when I click Confirm Delete button but nothing happened. I figure that it did not execute code from delete-data.php. Can anyone check problem on my AJAX.

> index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Add Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Button to trigger the deletion and show the modal -->
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete Data</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap Modal for the alert -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure you want to delete the data?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirmDelete">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Bootstrap Success Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="successModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="successModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="successModalLabel">Success</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Data has been successfully deleted.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap Error Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="errorModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="errorModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="errorModalLabel">Error</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                An error occurred while deleting the data.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- Add Bootstrap JS and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Your JavaScript code -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#confirmDelete").click(function() {
                // Make an AJAX request to your server to delete data from the database
                // Upon successful deletion, show a success modal
                // Otherwise, show an error modal
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete_data.php", // Replace with your server-side script URL
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response === "success") {
                            $('#deleteModal').modal('hide'); // Close the confirmation modal
                            $('#successModal').modal('show'); // Show a success modal
                        } else {
                            $('#deleteModal').modal('hide'); // Close the confirmation modal
                            $('#errorModal').modal('show'); // Show an error modal
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

> delete_data.php

```
<?php
// Your database connection code here
//header('Content-Type: application/json');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Perform the data deletion operation in your database
    // Replace this with your actual deletion code

    // Example deletion code
    $deleted = true; // Assume the data was successfully deleted

    if ($deleted) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
    
    /*if ($deleted) {
        echo json_encode(array("status" => "success"));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("status" => "error"));
    }*/

}
?>
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what error you get but I think there should be one in your browser's Console when this happens. And that would almost certainly make your question a duplicate of [My javascript is returning this error: $.ajax is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212202/my-javascript-is-returning-this-error-ajax-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the answers here helped me. The problem was: I was using the slim build of jQuery, which had some things removed, ajax being one of them.

The solution: Just download the regular (compressed or not) version of jQuery [here](https://jquery.com/%20download/#jquery) and include it in your project.

@Gus
[TypeError: $.ajax(...) is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271251/typeerror-ajax-is-not-a-function)

[image]

[image]

Comment: use `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank so very much sir ! You really my lifesaver ! :"D I am very happy now. Thank you thank you sir. I have include this script but nothing happened <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script> . Well maybe I include 2 jquery thats why it cannot read ?

Comment: You should include jquery library only one time. not 2 times.

Comment: Hahah I'm still learning and I get it now. Thank you so much sir ! :D

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Hello sir, sorry for disturbing & I am not pushing you but can you help me with this if you know what are the problem. I tried to implement this issues into my code but I found that it still occur the same problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/77430120/13719647

Comment: what is value  this in console `console.log(response); `?

Comment: nothing appear sir

Comment: change this button type `submit` to `button`  `<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnTambahNotis" type="button" name="submit">Tambah Notis</button>`

Comment: It really worked sir ! :"D Thank you so much sir ! May your life be filled with happiness and success always ! I have been finding many solution in about 1 week with this modal thing but I am dumb enough to find the solution. Thank you very much sir. 

Sir, can you comment your answer in the link I provided so I can approve your answer or do you still want me to make simple php file sir?

Comment: Added as answer in your question link. Glad to help you :)