# Modal Bootstrap Does Not Show

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I have problem where the modal is not show when data is already save in the database. The data is save into database but the modal is not show when it was success. The data is from form pass into AJAX. If I did not input anything in form, the modalEmpty is show. The thing is it do not show the ModalSuccess.

This is new updated tambahnotisphp.php

> NEW UPDATED tambahnotisphp.php

```
    <?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    /*include('connection.php');
    $conn=Connect();*/

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mbjbnotis", "root", "");
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $idPengguna = "DI200017";

    $nomborFail = $_POST['nomborFail'];
    $ulasan = nl2br($_POST['ulasan']);
    $status1 = "BELUM SELESAI";

    $tarikhNotisKeluar = $_POST['tarikhNotisKeluar'];

    $futureDate30Days = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tarikhNotisKeluar . ' +30 days'));
    $futureDate60Days = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tarikhNotisKeluar . ' +60 days'));

    $query = "INSERT INTO notis(nomborFail, ulasan, tarikhNotisKeluar, tarikhNotis1, tarikhNotis2, status, idPengguna) 
              VALUES(:nomborFail, :ulasan, :tarikhNotisKeluar, :futureDate30Days, :futureDate60Days, :status1, :idPengguna)";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nomborFail', $nomborFail);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ulasan', $ulasan);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tarikhNotisKeluar', $tarikhNotisKeluar);
    $stmt->bindParam(':futureDate30Days', $futureDate30Days);
    $stmt->bindParam(':futureDate60Days', $futureDate60Days);
    $stmt->bindParam(':status1', $status1);
    $stmt->bindParam(':idPengguna', $idPengguna);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }

    $conn = null; // Close the database connection
}
?>
```

Here i include all code from page tambahnotis.php

> ALL CODE FROM tambahnotis.php

```
    <?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['idPengguna']) && !isset($_SESSION['namaPengguna'])){
header("location: index.php"); 

}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <title>Sistem Notis MBJB</title>
    <!-- CSS files -->
    <link href="./dist/css/tabler.min.css?1684106062" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="./dist/css/tabler-flags.min.css?1684106062" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="./dist/css/tabler-payments.min.css?1684106062" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="./dist/css/tabler-vendors.min.css?1684106062" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="./dist/css/demo.min.css?1684106062" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style>
      @import url('https://rsms.me/inter/inter.css');
      :root {
        --tblr-font-sans-serif: 'Inter Var', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, San Francisco, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
      }
      body {
        font-feature-settings: "cv03", "cv04", "cv11";
      }
    </style>
      
    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="jquery3.7.1.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>-->
  </head>
<script>
function checkUsername(nomborFail){

   //var usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

   //if(usernameRegex.test(nomborFail)){
      document.getElementById('uname_response').innerHTML ="";

      if(nomborFail.length > 4){

         // AJAX request
         var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhttp.open("POST", "ajaxfile.php", true); 
         xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
         xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

               // Response
               var response = this.responseText; 
               document.getElementById('uname_response').innerHTML = response;
            }
         };
         var data = {nomborFail: nomborFail};
         xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
   //}else{
      //document.getElementById('uname_response').innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>Sila isikan nombor fail.</span>";
   //}

}

</script>
  <body>
    <!--<script src="./dist/js/demo-theme.min.js?1684106062"></script>-->
    <div class="page">
      <!-- Navbar -->
      <header class="navbar navbar-expand-md d-print-none" >
        <div class="container-xl">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar-menu" aria-controls="navbar-menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <h1 class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-autodark d-none-navbar-horizontal pe-0 pe-md-3">
            <a href="./aHome.php">
              <img src="./logo/logo.png" width="110" height="32" alt="MBJB" class="navbar-brand-image">
            </a>
          </h1>
          <div class="navbar-nav flex-row order-md-last">
            <div class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link d-flex lh-1 text-reset p-0" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-label="Open user menu">
                <span class="avatar avatar-sm">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M12 12m-9 0a9 9 0 1 0 18 0a9 9 0 1 0 -18 0" /><path d="M12 10m-3 0a3 3 0 1 0 6 0a3 3 0 1 0 -6 0" /><path d="M6.168 18.849a4 4 0 0 1 3.832 -2.849h4a4 4 0 0 1 3.834 2.855" /></svg>
                  </span>
                <div class="d-none d-xl-block ps-2">
                  <div><?php echo $_SESSION['namaPengguna']; ?></div>
                  <div class="mt-1 small text-muted"><?php echo $_SESSION['aksesPengguna']; ?></div>
                </div>
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end dropdown-menu-arrow">
                <a href="./profil.php" class="dropdown-item">Profil</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a href="./logout.php" class="dropdown-item">Log Keluar</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <header class="navbar-expand-md">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu">
          <div class="navbar">
            <div class="container-xl">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./aHome.php" >
                    <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block"><!-- Download SVG icon from http://tabler-icons.io/i/home -->
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M5 12l-2 0l9 -9l9 9l-2 0" /><path d="M5 12v7a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2v-7" /><path d="M9 21v-6a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v6" /></svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="nav-link-title">
                      Laman Utama
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./tambahnotis.php" >
                    <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block"><!-- Download SVG icon from http://tabler-icons.io/i/home -->
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 11l3 3l8 -8" /><path d="M20 12v6a2 2 0 0 1 -2 2h-12a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-12a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h9" /></svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="nav-link-title">
                      Tambah Notis
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./semua.php" >
                    <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block"><!-- Download SVG icon from http://tabler-icons.io/i/home -->
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 11l3 3l8 -8" /><path d="M20 12v6a2 2 0 0 1 -2 2h-12a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-12a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h9" /></svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="nav-link-title">
                      Semua
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./hampir.php" >
                    <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block"><!-- Download SVG icon from http://tabler-icons.io/i/home -->
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 11l3 3l8 -8" /><path d="M20 12v6a2 2 0 0 1 -2 2h-12a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-12a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h9" /></svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="nav-link-title">
                      Hampir
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./notis1.php" >
                    <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block"><!-- Download SVG icon from http://tabler-icons.io/i/checkbox -->
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 11l3 3l8 -8" /><path d="M20 12v6a2 2 0 0 1 -2 2h-12a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-12a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h9" /></svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="nav-link-title">
                      Notis 1
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./notis2.php" >
                    <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block"><!-- Download SVG icon from http://tabler-icons.io/i/checkbox -->
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 11l3 3l8 -8" /><path d="M20 12v6a2 2 0 0 1 -2 2h-12a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-12a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h9" /></svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="nav-link-title">
                      Notis 2
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                  
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./notis3.php" >
                    <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block"><!-- Download SVG icon from http://tabler-icons.io/i/checkbox -->
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 11l3 3l8 -8" /><path d="M20 12v6a2 2 0 0 1 -2 2h-12a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-12a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h9" /></svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="nav-link-title">
                      Notis 3
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                  
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./notis4.php" >
                    <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block"><!-- Download SVG icon from http://tabler-icons.io/i/checkbox -->
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 11l3 3l8 -8" /><path d="M20 12v6a2 2 0 0 1 -2 2h-12a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-12a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h9" /></svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="nav-link-title">
                      Notis 4
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                  
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./notis5.php" >
                    <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block"><!-- Download SVG icon from http://tabler-icons.io/i/checkbox -->
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 11l3 3l8 -8" /><path d="M20 12v6a2 2 0 0 1 -2 2h-12a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-12a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h9" /></svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="nav-link-title">
                      Notis 5
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                  
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./selesai.php" >
                    <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block"><!-- Download SVG icon from http://tabler-icons.io/i/checkbox -->
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 11l3 3l8 -8" /><path d="M20 12v6a2 2 0 0 1 -2 2h-12a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-12a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h9" /></svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="nav-link-title">
                        Selesai
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                
                
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./pengguna.php" >
                    <span class="nav-link-icon d-md-none d-lg-inline-block"><!-- Download SVG icon from http://tabler-icons.io/i/ghost -->
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M12 12m-9 0a9 9 0 1 0 18 0a9 9 0 1 0 -18 0" /><path d="M12 10m-3 0a3 3 0 1 0 6 0a3 3 0 1 0 -6 0" /><path d="M6.168 18.849a4 4 0 0 1 3.832 -2.849h4a4 4 0 0 1 3.834 2.855" /></svg>
                    </span>
                    <span class="nav-link-title">
                      Pengguna
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="page-wrapper">
        <!-- Page header -->
        <div class="page-header d-print-none">
          <div class="container-xl">
            <div class="row g-2 align-items-center">
              <div class="col">
                <h2 class="page-title">
                  Borang Tambah Notis
                </h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Page body -->
        <div class="page-body">
          <div class="container-xl">
            <!-- Content here -->
            <div class="row row-cards">
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-xl-3">
                      
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-6">
                      <div class="row row-cards">
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <form class="card">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                  <div class="form-label required">Nombor Fail</div>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomborFail" id="nomborFail" required="" onkeyup="checkUsername(this.value);">
                                  <div id="uname_response" ></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                  <div class="form-label required">Ulasan</div>
                                  <textarea class="form-control" name="ulasan" id="ulasan" rows="4" cols="50" required=""></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                  <div class="form-label required">Tarikh Notis Siasatan Dikeluarkan</div>
                                  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="tarikhNotisKeluar" id="tarikhNotisKeluar" required="">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                  <div class="row align-items-center">
                                    <div class="col"></div>
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnTambahNotis" type="submit" name="submit">Tambah Notis</button>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                          </form>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-xl-3">
                      
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="footer footer-transparent d-print-none">
          <div class="container-xl">
            <div class="row text-center align-items-center flex-row-reverse">
              <div class="col-lg-auto ms-lg-auto">
                
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-lg-auto mt-3 mt-lg-0">
                <ul class="list-inline list-inline-dots mb-0">
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    Copyright &copy; 2023
                    <a href="https://www.mbjb.gov.my/" class="link-secondary">MBJB</a>.
                    All rights reserved.
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                      v1.0.0-beta19
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal modal-blur fade" id="modalSuccess" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modal-title">Berjaya</div>
            <div>Notis Siasatan berjaya ditambah</div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Okay</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="modal modal-blur fade" id="modalError" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modal-title">Tidak Berjaya</div>
            <div>Notis Siasatan tidak berjaya ditambah</div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Okay</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="modal modal-blur fade" id="modalEmpty" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modal-title">Kosong</div>
            <div>Isikan semua butiran</div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Okay</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="modal modal-blur fade" id="modalSimpanData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modal-title">Simpan Data?</div>
            <div>Adakah anda ingin menyimpan data ini?</div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link link-secondary me-auto" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-green" id="simpanData">Simpan</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnTambahNotis").click(function() {
                var nomborFail = $("#nomborFail").val();
                var ulasan = $("#ulasan").val();
                var tarikhNotisKeluar = $("#tarikhNotisKeluar").val();
                // Check if the form fields are not empty
                if (nomborFail.trim() === "" || ulasan.trim() === "" || tarikhNotisKeluar.trim() === "") {
                    // Display an error message or alert
                    $('#modalEmpty').modal('show');
                    return;
                }
                // Make an AJAX request to your server to delete data from the database
                // Upon successful deletion, show a success modal
                // Otherwise, show an error modal
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "tambahnotisphp.php", // Replace with your server-side script URL
                    data: { nomborFail: nomborFail, ulasan: ulasan, tarikhNotisKeluar: tarikhNotisKeluar },
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log("AJAX Request Successful");
                        console.log(response); // Add this line to log the response
                        if (response.trim() === "success") {
                            $('#modalSuccess').modal('show');
                        } else {
                            $('#modalError').modal('show');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("AJAX Request Failed");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <!-- Libs JS -->
    <!-- Tabler Core -->
    <script src="./dist/js/tabler.min.js?1684106062" defer></script>
    <!--<script src="./dist/js/demo.min.js?1684106062" defer></script>-->
      
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the code definitely enter the "success" function? Perhaps there was an error before that? Have you tried to do any debugging? Use your browser's Developer Tools to see what's going on. The problem is not obvious just from reading the code.

Comment: Check for any console logs / errors

Comment: Ps. Your php/sql code is vulnerable to sql injection and syntax errors. Use prepared statements and parameters to avoid these problems.  See https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli

Comment: Side note: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). Even [if you are escaping inputs, it's not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API instead of concatenating user-provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: I have check but nothing appear on console. I already include latest tambahnotis.php and tambahnotisphp.php. Can someone check for me what are the problem? I'm stuck and don't understand why.

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, or a JS problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: I also do not know what are the problem. Maybe html problem? I am not sure because I am still learning in this. But Sir Vel already help me with this, you can see the answer that I approved. @NicoHaase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change button type `submit` to `button` in modal button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnTambahNotis" type="button" name="submit"> Tambah Notis </button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir :D This is really worked ! Modal already can show after I change type="button"

Answer (score -1):

Try sending a JSON formatted response from `tamabahnotisphp.php`.
I'm pretty sure that the request can't process a plain-text response.

Comment: Ajax can process any type of response